# Regex to match any number except 0 and 1 consisting of max four digits

Tags: regex

I tried the following to match any number except 0 and 1 (say, 2 to 9999), but it does not seem to work as desired.

```
\d[0-9]?[0-9]?[^0-1]*
```

Comment: In what way does it not work as desired? (Please add some examples of failure cases.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can match all numbers from 2 to 9999 using

```
\b(?![01]\b)\d{1,4}\b
```

Or (if you have individual strings)

```
^(?![01]$)\d{1,4}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT8nJ3/12)

The `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead that is used here to define exceptions.

**More details**

- `\b` - word boundary (if `^` is used - start of the string)
- `(?![01]\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `0` or `1` (`[01]` is a character class that matches a single char from the set defined in the class) as a whole word (or string if `$` is used instead of `\b`)
- `\d{1,4}` - 1, 2, 3 or 4 digits
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary (no digit, letter or `_` can appear immediately to the right, if there can be a letter or `_`, replace with `(?!\d)`).

Comment: Note that it will be harder with decimal/float values, but with integers, it is really simple.

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you, or if you need more assistance with it.

Answer (score 10):

Exclude `0` and `1` from character class in `regex`.

```
[2-9]{1}\d{0,3}
```

This will match all the numbers which **does not starts with** `0` and `1`.

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fV0eV0/1)

**EDIT**

To match **all numbers except `0` and `1`**

```
[2-9]{1,4}
```

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fV0eV0/3)

Comment: I think this is not what the OP wanted. He wants to find all numbers from 2 to 9999 and not exclude the cyphers 0 and 1 by default.

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh Check the `Edit` in answer

Comment: @Tushar I think only `[2-9]{1,4}` will do!!?

Comment: But [2-9]{1,4} will not allow 1212, which is valid, he only wants to exclude the **numbers** 0 and 1, not the **cyphers**

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh My first answer `[2-9]{1}\d{0,3}` will do

Comment: No, you first number will also not allow 1212, as you exclude 1 as the first cypher.

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh  Not sure which one OP wants, so added both

Comment: @Tushar yes but BOTH of your solutions do not allow the number 1234, which is between 2 and 9999.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all numbers between 2 and 9999, you'd need to check two cases, either if it's a length-1 number and then exclude cyphers 0 and 1, or allow everything, if the length is > 1. So the solutions would be something like:

```
(([2-9]{1})|([1-9]{1}[0-9]{1,}))
```

This does not allow 0 and 1, but allows 111, 322, 20, or 24.

Answer (score -1):

This should match anything between 1 and infinity and match 1 or more digit from 1 to 9 trailing by 0 or more 0.

- 1
- 10
- 11
- 100
- 101010101
- 99
- even 42 works

but it's wont work for 003 004 024:

```
[1-9]+[0-9]{0,}
```

Comment: As much as this wasn't an answer that the OP was asking, it did help me in a different situation, to capture all all numbers 1+and up, without 0.