# How do I ignore 0 value for price validation using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have problem with my price validation regular expression.

My pattern **does not accept values** that **I want** such as:

- 101.00
- 110.00
- 1000.00
- 0.50

My pattern accepts values such as:

- 1.00
- 1.10
- 1.11
- 11.11

Right now, my pattern is `^([1-9]+\.)(\d{2})$`.

Desired regexp should not accept 'zero' values like e.g. `0.00` or `0`.

Comment: ^([0-9]+.)(\d{2})$

Comment: What is a "zero value," you are speaking vaguely?

Comment: `[1-9]` does not match a zero, use `[0-9]`

Comment: How about `00000.00`? Is it considered valid?

Comment: Why are you doing this in regex? JS has [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) which you can use to simply check against zero.

Comment: that expression still excepts 0.00, i dont want when user input products price, they can put $0 for example. FYI, this is for price validation where seller can input product price. I don't want user(seller) have the ability to input value just '0' or '0.00)'

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/31514495/372239

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
/^(?!0.00)(\d+\.)(\d\d)$/
```

```js
[
  '0','0.00',
  '101.00','110.00','1000.00','0.50',
  '1.00','1.10','1.11','11.11'
].map(x=>
  console.log( x, /^(?!0.00)(\d+\.)(\d\d)$/.test(x) )
);
```

Comment: thanks! but i found another flaw which is, its accepts values such as below:
00.00, 000.00

Comment: also, is it possible to ignore value IF the price is starting with 0 unless there's a number after decimal points? such as 0101.00 or 01000.00 need to ignore

Answer (score 1):

The expression [`/^(0\.(?!00)|(?!0)\d+\.)\d\d$/`](https://regex101.com/r/gjKkdn/1) satisfies all your requirements (so far). It seems easier to handle the cases *0.x* and *y.z* as two alternatives.